# Condition in controller

Tags: asp.net

i want to display fidele client who have as type fidele  and client in database(Id,Nom,CodeClient,telephone,type):  type is int 1 :fidele else 0: non fidele.

```
 public ActionResult ListefideleClients()
        {

            CRUDEntities db = new CRUDEntities();

            var model = db.Client.ToList();
            return View("ListeClients", model);
        }
```

can someone help me to fix it

Comment: Simply use `Where`: - `db.Client.Where(x => x.type == 1).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple put this in your

```
  dynamic model = db.Client.Where(x => x.Type == 1).ToList();
```